# ListViewItems replace specific character

Tags: vb.net

I am facing a problem replacing specific characters of some `ListViewItems`.

I have tried this code:

```
 For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListView1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("badword") Then
            ListView1.Items(i) = ListView1.Items(i).ToString.Replace("badword", "")
        End If
 Next
```

But this causes an error:

> String cannot be converted to ListViewItems

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. It will give you some clues on what's actually happening.

Comment: it's already on and the error also included in the question

Comment: What's the problem then? You have the error and the visual clue. Change to `If ListView1.Items(i).Text.Contains("badword") Then` and  `ListView1.Items(i).Text = ListView1.Items(i).Text.Replace("badword", "")`. You are by now accessing a `ListViewItem` Object, not it's Text property. It's like writing `TextBox1 = "Some Text"`. The comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: Try declaring i as an integer before using it. Or in your for loop use`for i As Integer`

Comment: You are probably confused because the ListViewItem constructor accepts a string, it assigns the Text property.  You must use the Text property to make this code work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the error suggests, you cannot assign a string to an object of type ListViewItems.

Try this: (this is in C#, but you can do similar in VB.Net)

```
ListView1.Items[i].Text = ListView1.Items[i].Text.Replace("badword", "");
```